# How to check if there is such x (in X) for which y is 'false' and then mark the whole set X 'false'?

Tags: java, arrays

For example, I have 2 char arrays and I want to compare them. If even one of chars doesn't match (is marked as 'false'), program should return 'false' for the whole array.

Comment: Are you working with arrays or sets (you use both terms, which are far from equivalent in Java)? If arrays (or other ordered data structure) do you want to compare corresponding positions or do you want to use some sort of "contains" test? Where are you having a problem, exactly?

Comment: I want to know if there is a simple way to ask program if something occured, like if there was any 'false' while checking compatibility of chars in two arrays.

Comment: There is a simple way to do that, yes.

Comment: The position of chars should be the same in two arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a for loop to iterate through the method. then comapare the two arrays using if(chararray1[i] != chararray2[i]) then simply put a return false; inside that, and a return true outside the loop.

Here is some pseudocode:

```
 for(int i = 0;i < length;i++)
     if(chararray1[i] != chararray2[i])
            return false;
  return true;
```